# Making a series of inputs look like a actual fractions

Tags: javascript, html, fractions

Given the following in HTML5 based coding in Notepad++, how would i make an **actual fraction of A/B and C/D** ?

Why: I want to make my A/B and C/D look like a actual fraction <sup>A</sup>/<sub>B</sub> + <sup>C</sup>/<sub>D</sub> and have the `input` boxes arranged in the same fashion.

> The Code works as written, I just want to be able to expand it but
>   having difficulty finding out how to do so online.

```html
<div id="Section_1">
 <p style='font-size: 4;'></p>
 Please tell me what you are adding?
 **Placement Matters**
 Now we are going to input A / B + C / D
 A=<input type="number" id="AbsoluteA" size='6'>
 B=<input type="number" id="AbsoluteB" size='6'>
 C=<input type="number" id="AbsoluteC" size='6'>
 D=<input type="number" id="AbsoluteD" size='6'>
 <p id="FAILEDHERE"></p>
  <button onclick="Script1()" id="button2">Proceed</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to display “Classic” built-up fractions with an horizontal line in HTML?

Comment: Yeah... its been a pain finding a individual line of code to set that up

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way for doing this. See the fllowing examples:

**Example 1** ( ½ + ¾ )

```
&frac12; + &frac34;
```

**Example 2** ( <sup>A</sup>⁄<sub>B</sub> + <sup>C</sup>⁄<sub>D</sub> )

```
<sup>A</sup>&frasl;<sub>B</sub> + <sup>C</sup>&frasl;<sub>D</sub>
```

But to put the input box instead of the text, you have to act in a different way. Because using the example above does not a good result for the `<input>` box. See the examples below:

**ٍExample 3:** (Using table)

```css
table,
span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle
}
input {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom:solid 1px">
            <input type="text" size=3 placeholder="A">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size=3 placeholder="B">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<span> + </span>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom:solid 1px">
            <input type="text" size=3 placeholder="C">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" size=3 placeholder="D">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Example 4:** (Using CSS)

```js
function Script1() {
  var A = +document.getElementById( 'AbsoluteA' ).value,
        B = +document.getElementById( 'AbsoluteB' ).value,
        C = +document.getElementById( 'AbsoluteC' ).value,
        D = +document.getElementById( 'AbsoluteD' ).value;

  document.getElementById( 'result' ).innerText = ( A / B ) + ( C / D ) || 0
}
```

```css
.frac {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center
}
.frac span {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em
}
.frac span.bottom {
  border-top: thin solid black
}
input {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none
}
```

```html
<div class="frac">
    <span>
        <input type="text" id="AbsoluteA" size=3 placeholder="A">
    </span>
    <span class="bottom">
        <input type="text" id="AbsoluteB" size=3 placeholder="B">
    </span>
</div>

<span> + </span>

<div class="frac">
    <span>
        <input type="text" id="AbsoluteC" size=3 placeholder="C">
    </span>
    <span class="bottom">
        <input type="text" id="AbsoluteD" size=3 placeholder="D">
    </span>
</div>

<button onclick="Script1()" id="button2" type="button"> = </button>

<span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: will all of these work as well with the "input boxes, so one box on top of the other?... scratch that I just read what you said under example 2

Comment: So I tried out all the fraction sections. but the one I liked that when you run the code snippet shows the fractions linked horizontally, but when I run it in my code they stack vertically and I cannot quite figure out how to fix that

Comment: Which method do you use? Do you use the table to display it? Don't forget to use `display: inline-block` for `<table>` and `<span>`s.

Comment: im not sure where that goes :( this is my first time building tables in HTML